# Algorithm for generate all solutions to a linear Diophantine equation

Tags: recursion, number-theory

Consider the linear Diophantine equation of the form:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_ix_i=n.$$
My goal is to list all the non-negative solutions to this equation. I wrote the following recursive algorithm, but I am not sure if it is the most efficient way to build the solutions. Here is the current version:

```
def recsolve(n, L, cursol, result = []):
if len(L) == 1:
    ak = L[0]
    if n%ak == 0:
        result.append(cursol + [n//ak])
    return

else:
    a1 = L[0]
    end = math.floor(n/a1)
    for k in range(0, end + 1):
        recsolve(n-k*a1,L[1:], cursol + [k],result)


result = []
n = 5
L = [1,2,3]
recsolve(n, L, [], result)
print(result, "; Number of solutions:", len(result))
```

I would be grateful if someone could suggest more efficient approaches to finding all solutions to a linear Diophantine equation.

Answer (score 1):

Your [current recursive solution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/102302/3) is pretty solid. It is, I believe, about the most efficient recursive approaches we can have for the general situation.

Somehow I prefer [the code in you first solution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/102302/1) since it is easier to read. All we need to make it correct is to change `return [None]` to `return []` and `if None not in res:` to `if res:`

Implementation-wise, we could change it to use an iterative method which should run faster. Also, we could sort $a_i$ in descending order which may improve the listing speed. For example, solutions for $100x_1+100x_2+x_3=1000$ will be found much faster than $x_1+100x_2+100x_3=1000$.

In some special cases, we might be able to speed up the performance. For example, for $15x_1+10x_2+6x_3=100000$, $x_1$ must be a multiple of 2, $x_2$ must be a multiple of 3, $x_3$ must be a multiple of 5. These restriction could help us to improve the speed if they are given or they can be found by factorization easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming. For each $j \leq k$ and $m \leq n$, find the number of solutions to
$$ \sum_{i=1}^j a_i x_i = m. $$
Details left to you.